# How can we prove equation of sub-gradient and conjugate?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How can we prove blow equation ?

$$
x^k\in\partial f^*(-M^Tp^k)
\implies
-Mx^k\in\partial[f^*\circ(-M^T)](p^k)
$$

Reference

- [On the Douglas—Rachford splitting method and the proximal point algorithm for maximal monotone operators](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01581204)

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x)+f^{*}(-M^Tp)=\langle x,-M^Tp\rangle
$$

$$
f^{**}(x)=\langle x,-M^Tp\rangle - f^{*}(-M^Tp)
$$

$$
\langle x,-M^Tp\rangle - f^*(-M^Tp)\geq \langle x,-M^Tq \rangle - f^{*}(-M^Tq) , \ \ \forall q
$$

$$
f^{*}(-M^Tq)\geq f^{*}(-M^Tp) + \langle x,M^Tp-M^Tq\rangle, \ \ 
\forall q
$$

$$
f^{*}\circ(-M^T)(q)\geq f^{*}\circ(-M^T)(p) + \langle -Mx, q-p\rangle, \ \ 
\forall q
$$

$$
-Mx \in \partial [f^{*}\circ(-M^T)](p)
$$